# ValueError when validating data

Tags: python, validation, valueerror

I am trying to make function, that returns True when value of `hcl` is correct with required specification (it's inside multi-line comment in the function). The first thing I wanted to check was if length of that value is correct (should be # + 6 other chars), and when that would be correct I would check if all chars are in group of a-f or 0-9 - and that was my idea to solve this problem, but unfortunately there is a

```
ValueError: substring not found
```

(when second elem of list goes to the function), that I don't understand(btw. as always, you have some reasoning, and when it there is a mistake you can't found it, because for you everything is working and this 'should work').

```
def check_hcl(line):
    '''
    a # followed by exactly six characters 0-9 or a-f.
    '''
    print(line[line.index(':')+1], len(line[line.index(':')+2:]))
    if line[line.index(':')+1] != '#' or len(line[line.index(':')+2:]) != 6:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    


list = ['hcl:#866857','#52a9af','#cfa07d','7d3b0c','#cc0362','#a9784']
                                            #false              #false
for i in list:
    print(check_hcl(i))
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to change print(line[line.index(':')+1] to print(line[line.index(':')+1:]. And also you do not have ':' character in other list element, this is why you get error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) method from the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import re

def check_hcl(line):
    if re.match("(.*?)#[a-f0-9]{6}", line):
        return True
    return False

list = ['hcl:#866857','#52a9af','#cfa07d','7d3b0c','#cc0362','#a9784']

for i in list:
    print(check_hcl(i))
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
False
True
False
```

---

Explanation:

The pattern `(.*?)#[a-f0-9]{6}` can be broken down to 3 parts:

1. `(.*?)` matches anything of any length, including substrings of length `0`.
2. `#` matches a `'#'`.
3. `[a-f0-9]{6}` matches a substring of characters `a` to `f` and numbers `0` to `9` of length `6`.

*Credits to @Ian.*

Comment: Awesome answer with even better explanation.  I would only comment that the stipulation would be that the character match, based on the question, must be a-f, so that would change \w{6} to [a-f0-9]{6} making the full regex expression re.match(r"(.*?)#[a-f0-9]{6}", line)